# collectionview on iOS to tall

Tags: maui

I have a .net maui application with a collection view. On Android it is correctly displayed. On iOS however it always assumes the height of thew windows despite other items being above it. so it runs too tall and the last item is cut off.

[image]

Scrolling works as expected.
My code is:

```
        <Grid RowDefinitions="40, Auto, *">
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="0,0,16,0"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            Text="{x:Static resources:Translations.AddBudgetLabel}"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Command="{Binding GoToAddBudgetCommand}" />

        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="18,6,12,6"
                               Spacing="6"
                               Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}"
                   Text="{x:Static resources:Translations.MonthlyBudgetLabel}" />
            <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}"
                   Text="{Binding BudgetedAmount, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <CollectionView Grid.Row="2"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Budgets}"
                        SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="budget:BudgetListItemViewModel">
                    <Grid Padding="12,6,12,8">
                        <controls:Card HeightRequest="80" Padding="12">
                            <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Command="{Binding ViewModel.EditBudgetCommand, Source={x:Reference BudgetList}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Border.GestureRecognizers>

                            <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="6">
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource TextHead}"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />

                                <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding SpendingPercentage}" />

                                <Grid>
                                    <Label
                                        Text="{Binding CurrentSpending, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}" />

                                    <Label
                                        Text="{Binding SpendingLimit, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </controls:Card>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource TextSubheadSecondary}"
                           Margin="10,0,10,0"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="{x:Static resources:Translations.NoBudgetsMessage}" />
                </Grid>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
```

I feel like this should be a rather basic view, so I'm confused what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: Are you saying that if you scroll to the bottom, it is not possible to get the last item in collection to fully appear? That would indeed be a Maui bug.  As a workaround, define another grid row that is only one or a few pixels high. Don’t even have to put anything there, just add to row definitions. Does that avoid the bug?

Comment: Might also calculate better if do CollectionView ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems".

Comment: exactly. I can only pull the last item into the screen, but it bounces back out as soon as I release it. Adding the extra row unfortunately does not help. It seems the "*" is always resolved to the max size of the page. When I replace it with for exaomple 600 it works as expected. But obviously that is only on that one device alright then

Comment: ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems" did not change anything either unfortunately.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9135 - fix should be in next release. See issue for possible workaround.

Comment: ah, thanks for that! I tried the work around but unfortnately it didn't really work for me. But potentially I can adapt it a bit to make it work - or hope that the fix is back portet to the june release.

Comment: Looks like you are using custom control in `CollectionView`. Do you mean that you've tried [this workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9135#issuecomment-1398493085) and failed to work?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT exactly, that is the one. The custom control I have in the collection view is literally just a border with the shadow property set

Comment: @NPadrutt Thanks for the update, you may need wait for the next release to get it fixed.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT do you mean the one coming next week or are we talking about 8.0 in november?

Comment: So.. this WAS fixed at one point on the 7.0 Branch. But since I moved to 8.0 or the 7.0.96 (to which this fix was backported) the issue is back..

Comment: I feel like it doesn't notice that there is a shell wrapper around it and with that a tab page at the bottom.  @AlexandarMay-MSFT Do I have to adjust anything specifically to make this work?